# Windows 11 IIS missing installed features

Tags: windows, iis

I attempted to reinstall IIS by removing and readding it through "Add features". These are my settings, which match settings on a PC with a working IIS. The Manager doesn't show any of these features.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Compared to working machine: https://pasteboard.co/AttuU8HmjilT.png

localhost returns a 503 and also shuts down the DefaultAppPool. Message from Event Viewer:

> Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

UPDATE:
Maybe this could help. If I try to install a module (such as URL Rewrite), I get the following error:

> The IIS 7.0 CoreWebEngine and W3SVC features must be installed to use IIS URL Rewrite Module 2.

[image]

UPDATE 2:

I think I'm getting somewhere... This is what I did:

1. Add the same keys from a working machine (lots of mine were missing, CoreWebEngine included) Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components
   **[image: strong text]**
2. Try localhost and check Application logs for error. It would say one of the dll's failed to load.
   [image]
3. Go to "Turn Windows features on or off" and readd the corresponding feature.
4. Finally, localhost started returning 401 and I'm able to install modules like URL Rewrite. Default website still doesn't work but that's a different issue. I will create a new question for that.

Comment: And have you rebooted the PC after re-adding?

Comment: @YisroelTech about a hundred times :)

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Its a silly limitation and should be removed imho but thats offtopic. May have to start a Meta thread about that.

Comment: @JohnSmith do you by chance have VMWare Server installed on the machine?

Comment: @YisroelTech nope

Comment: @DrMoishePippik nothing helps

Answer (score 1):

From an online search for that error message, the issue might be due to IIS [URL ReWrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)  not [recognizing the version number for Windows 11](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e78fc60-70e2-4487-b973-b33648bd361b/why-iis-100-can-not-be-install-url-rewrite-20-in-win-10-preview?forum=iiswebplatforminstaller). This can be fixed with a Registry hack:

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>, type *rege*, and select *Regedit*
- Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp`
- Edit value `MajorVersion` and set to `9`.
- Press <kbd>F5</kbd> while in *Regedit*.
- Now install [the ReWrite 2.0 module](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/professional-microsoft-iis/9781118417379/c19_level1_2.xhtml) (and possibly reinstall IIS).
- In *Regedit*, change `MajorVersion` back to `10` *decimal* (`a` *hexadecimal*).

See [Common registry keys that are used by many parts of IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/general/use-registry-keys) for more information.

Comment: I tried it but not luck. What did work was readding all the keys to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components

I will update my question with details

Comment: @JohnSmith, it appears you have a good **answer** with specific Registry edits. Rather than edit the *question*, it's valid to write an answer to your own question, and have it accepted so others looking for that information know it's accepted. Glad you got it to work!